# SDL Texture transparent background

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

This is probably rather simple problem, but after an hour of searching and trying I still didn't manage to solve it. 
I have two png files. One is a background image and second is foreground. The foreground has an alpha channel. I want to display foreground on top of background.

I'm loading foreground using:

```
SDL_Surface *clip = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0xff);
SDL_Rect rect = { x, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
SDL_BlitSurface(map, &rect, clip, NULL);
*block = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, clip);
```

Where map is some SDL_Surface.

I'm loadin backgroun using:

```
SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path);
//Create texture from surface pixels
SDL_Texture* newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
```

Then I trying to connect them:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, background, NULL, &cur);
SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, map, NULL, &cur);
```

But it results in foreground image with black background. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);`.

Comment: It doesn't help. Any other idea?

Comment: I think you shouldn't mix up renderer with surface. They are different things! Use the renderer for background too.

Answer (score 4):

You should add these 2 lines,

```
Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_SetColorKey(loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, colorkey);
```

before this line in your code

```
SDL_Texture* newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, loadedSurface);
```